# Azure DevOps Pipeline as Code and Deployment Group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm facing the challenge to use the same resource (VM in my company)  for all my dev environment. That means that multiple apps will be deployed there.

I have:
https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/project1 with a Pipeline as Code for CI/CD & environment called D-Stage
https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/project2 with a Pipeline as Code for CI/CD & environment called D-Stage

Since I can’t use Deployment group, each time I register the VM as a Resource of each project’s pipeline, if I don’t change the registration name, one reg replace another and the last registration is the only one that has connection to the VM.
On the other side if I create a new registration I get a new azure agent per project.

What should be the right way to handle the scenarios since Deployment Group is not supported in YAML files?

Comment: `if I don’t change the registration name, one reg replace another and the last registration is the only one that has connection to the VM. On the other side if I create a new registration I get a new azure agent per project.`  I am confused about this. Can you elaborate on this (better with screenshot)?

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I mean if I don't update a parameter of the registration script (screen add new resource)  __--agent $env:COMPUTERNAME__ to __--agent $env:COMPUTERNAME-projectName__ one resource registration replace  the other.

Comment: Yes, if you want to add multiple resources in a VM environment, and the resources refer to the same VM, you need to modify the agent name in the Registration script, otherwise the resource with the same agent name will replace the previously registered resource. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDqgE.png). So do you want to display multiple resources with the same name in an environment?

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I'm actually doing in that way. 
Just wanted to confirm if this is the correct way in yaml files, because using releases and deploy group I did not face this multiple registration agents.

Comment: Yes, it is the right way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to add multiple resources in a VM environment, and the resources refer to the same VM, we need to modify the agent name in the registration script, otherwise the resource with the same agent name will replace the previously registered resource.

By modifying the agent name(`--agent $env:COMPUTERNAME`) in the registration script, we can register multiple agents in a VM environment:

[image]